# Не понимаю принцип работы с LikedList в Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Задание.

> Создайте однонапрямленный список и удалите все элементы между элементами со значениями "X" и "Z". напечатать оба списка.

Я первокурсник, обьясните пожалуйста суть ошибки как для чайника. 
Мой код:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ApLab4 {
    static String scanner(){
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write a string of symbols");
        String userInputString = userInput.nextLine();
        return userInputString;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add(scanner());
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(list.contains('X'));
        if(list.contains("X") && list.contains("Z")){
            for (int i = list.indexOf("X") + 1; i < list.indexOf("Z") ; i++) {

                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос: 1) в чем проблема? код не работает? 2) исходные данные и нужный результат

Comment: Полностью задание выложите

Answer (score 1):

Твоя ошибка в том что ты **не заполнял список элементами**, а добавлял один элемент и сразу проверял его на нахождения между x и z!
Пользуйся отладчиком всегда и поймешь в чем ошибка!
Попробуй такой вариант:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ApLab4 {

    // Для примера пусть длинна списка будет 6
    private static final int listLength = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // Переменная для считывания и записи в список
        String string;

        // Создаем список LinkedList так как его скорость удаления/вставки выше чем у ArrayList
        LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

        // заполняем его символами
        for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
            string = reader.readLine();
            linkedList.add(string);
        }

        System.out.println("Изначальный вид списка: " + linkedList);

        // теперь удаляем элемнты между X Z
        if(linkedList.contains("x") && linkedList.contains("z")){
            for (int i = linkedList.indexOf("x") + 1; i < linkedList.indexOf("z") ; i++) {

                linkedList.remove(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(linkedList);

    }
}
```